# Why is "size on disk" much bigger than "size" when I copy data from NTFS to exFAT?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs, disk-space, exfat

I tried to backup from my NTFS external hard drive to a new exFAT external hard drive. When the copy finished I saw that I have very little free space remained. I checked my file size and I saw that the real size of my file is *"30.4GB"* but the size on disk is *"396 GB"*.

I must mention that number of file is so high (about 96110 Files, 10807 Folders).

Why has this happened? How should I fix this? I formatted my new hard drive with exFAT filesystem with A*llocation unit size* of **4096 kilobytes**.

Comment: What about hidden or system files? How many files are there? Which sizes?

Comment: there are no hidden files or system files

Comment: You copy single file `30.4GB`?

Comment: @week I edit my question , no about 96k files

Comment: Why would you set the allocation unit size so ridiculously high?

Comment: The allocation unit is the smallest size a non-empty file can have.  If you have a lot of very small files they will each take 4 MB.  Consider another filesystem or zipping the files.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the default cluster size on exFAT is already high [Why is exFAT's default allocation size in Windows so high?](https://superuser.com/q/1151976/241386), [1-byte file takes up 2 MB (yes, megabytes) on 6 TB exFAT Veracrypt volume. Why?](https://superuser.com/q/1272907/241386)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If my calculations are right than average file size on your exFAT is 331,7KB, but you've set minimal unit size to 4096 KB, which means that there is 92% unused space in every unit, so 96110 (files) x 3768,32 (freespace) = 362173235,2 KB = 345,40 GB (free) + 30,4 (real) = 375,8 GB, still missing few gigs somewhere, maybe because of that average size.

In other words, set unit size as small as possible or use ".tar" or something like that.