# Copy file with ADS (Alternate Data Streams) via Network loses hidden streams?

Tags: networking, filesystems, ntfs, alternate-data-stream

Thanking to this answer https://superuser.com/a/704697/200806 I discovered ADS (Alternate Data Streams) and started to play some demo: created a test.txt:hidden file with hidden in ADS content. I can see from the same PC where I created it, but when I am copying it over network - hidden content is lost.

Both PC are on Win7x64, target drives are NTFS, connected via Team Viewer VPN (tried both RDP and Share copying - result the same: hidden content is lost)

Is ADS content persistent when copying over network in generally? 
If Yes Why in my case content may be lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd gather that Team Viewer stripped it out.  I copied several files but without using Teamviewer and the ADS were copied over.

Comment: I tried it via Gmail too - the same result. Will try tomorrow on real network.

Comment: Checked it on real network - it works.

Comment: btw, Skype also cuts ADS

Comment: It makes sense for them to strip it out.  There is no guarantee that the destination file system will support ADS.