# Folder Size 18.7gb but Size on disk 1.33TB - why/how could this have happened? Synology DS212 NAS RAID

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, disk-space

To start - I am way out of my comfort zone trying to fix this problem but I am not sure what else to do!

We have (2) 3TB hard drives in a Synology DS212 NAS RAID and are constantly running into issues of not having enough space. Even though we are uploading 30-90GB weekly, there is no way that we should be completely full at this point. I clicked on a folder in the drive and pulled up the properties. It says that the size is 18.7GB but the size on disk is 1.33TB.

[image: Screen shot from the folder properties.]

I researched and was brought to this site where [a question was answered](https://superuser.com/questions/704218/why-is-there-such-a-big-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk).

Ultimately I learned that clusters have a minimum size and we thought that might be the issue, but even if we have the largest allocation size possible: 32,768 KB * 3612 (number of files in that folder) it would still only take up 118 GB of extra space.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

As mentioned above, we upload photos and video files weekly (30-90gb) but after we export our raw camera files we delete those. Just thought that might be pertinent information.

Comment: Any additional information from the NAS itself (via the web interface)? Like reported used space, maybe errors... Preferably screenshots.

Comment: My only guess is that Windows is stupid.  For the reasons you already mentioned, this just isn't possible.  How much used/free space is reported on the volume as a whole?  If that shows much less space used, I'd go with that.

Comment: Can you use something other then Windows Explorer to determine the size?  I guarantee you there is a reason this is happening.

Comment: @Quietus - I am not sure and I am also not sure how to do that. I will ask my husband how to access the web interface and then provide screen shots.

Comment: @Ramhound - Unfortunately I am not very savvy in this area. Can you suggest what I should use to determine size?

Comment: @psusi the volume is almost completely full... I did another check today and ran the properties on a folder that was saved on my desktop hard drive and on the hard drive it said that the size was 50.7MB and size on disk is 51.5MB. I copied that folder onto the NAS drive and the size was the same, 50.7, but the size on disk is 108GB. Folder contains 432 files, 444 folders. I have a screen shot but I am not sure how to post it :-/

Comment: @LisaHamilton - Use the tool of your choice.  There are hundreds of choices pick the one you like.

Comment: It's because there was too much IO going in causing the folder to get very fragmented.

Answer (score 0):

I think we've found the answer! It appears that it might be an issue with Windows 8 and a Synology update. We will try and follow up! Here's where we found the answer... http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=76571