# Strange hard disk information after defrag

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, defragment

I just finished a defrag on one of my drives and I am now getting some bizarre info with regards the available space. I had half written this post titled *"Why has defragging used all my disk space"* but I changed it as I have found something very peculiar.

Once the defrag had finished, the defrag program showed me that the available space on the drive had massively reduced. The drive is a 3TB WD which, pre-defrag, had around 1.3TB of available space. Now it's finished I only have around 3GB free. Windows explorer also reports similar findings.

[image: Defraggler]

[image: Windows Explorer]

I though this was odd and wondered what could be now taking up all the available space, so I ran [Spacesniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/). This reports a reading more like what I would expect - 1.6TB used - so approx. 1.3TB available.

[image: Spacesniffer]

- The drive is used for backups so has a couple of large files on (as opposed to thousands of smaller ones)
- I used [Defraggler](https://www.piriform.com/defraggler/download) to defrag the drive
- It took 1 day and 17 hours
- The "Fragments Reduced" is -2786?!
- Windows 10 Enterprise
- WD Green 3TB

Comment: Possibly related to (?) http://superuser.com/questions/704218/why-is-there-such-a-big-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk (?) Also, google "defraggler volume shadow copy"

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Defragger.

Comment: Yup. Third party defrag programs FTL

Comment: Looks that way - I have never had problems with Defraggler but may steer clear in future. A disk-cleanup solved the problem. Thanks