# Win 10 reports bloated size on disk for NAS drive

Tags: hard-drive, nas

My friend has a Buffalo TS1200D NAS which has three folders mapped to drives on her Win 10 desktop computer. When I look at the drive in "NAS Navigator2" it tells me the disk usage is
37.2 GB/1830.3 GB (2.0%).

I had a look because zipped back-ups were too big to upload to the cloud storage. As you'll see from the linked screenshot, in Windows, the largest mapped drive shows the following properties:

- 28,254 files in 139 folders.
- size = 33.0 GB
- size on disk = 3.44 TB

[Link to screenshot of Windows Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh4E8.png)

How can the size on disk be _SO_MUCH_ bigger than the file size?

How can the size on disk be reported as being bigger than the size of the disk?!

It seems it's way more than you'd expect from cluster sizes that I've read about elsewhere. Noting the answers to [[this question](https://superuser.com/questions/704218/why-is-there-such-a-big-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk)] and assuming 32kB cluster size, the minimum size on disk would be:
28,254 x 32,000 = 0.9 GB
We seem to be in a *completely* different ball-park!

Other info: the NAS has 2 disks using RAID 1 and, to the best of my knowledge, all the default settings out of the box.

Any thoughts on this gratefully received :)

Comment: Without assuming anything, check the [real cluster size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81236/how-can-i-view-the-allocation-unit-size-of-a-ntfs-partition-in-vista).

Comment: thanks @harrymc - I'll verify within a couple of days.