# How can a folder have much larger `size on disk` than `size`?

Tags: ntfs, network-drive, size

I have a folder on a NTFS network drive. I had copied it over from my local NTFS drive. Its displayed size on the network drive is totally confusing to me:

```
Size:           1,34 GB
Size on Disk:   12,2 GB
```

How can there be a **tenfold** discrepancy between size and size on disk? And what is the true size now?

Comment: try defragmenting the drive and check size again...may be its the way in which a file is saved across different sectors of a HDD. You could also try deleting it and copying again

Comment: well its not my drive, guess I'll talk to the admin about it

Comment: wait so u copied a file from your local drive to the network drive ?

Comment: a complete folder yes. Isn't that what I'm saying in my OP?

Comment: and the folder size on your local drive is 1.34 GB ?

Comment: yes something like that

Comment: here you go: https://superuser.com/questions/704218/why-is-there-such-a-big-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk

Comment: hope it helps...

Comment: btw how many files do u have in the folder ?

Comment: Around 12.000 files. Thanks for the link. I'm not sure if the top answer there applies here as it talks about FAT instead of NTFS, but I guess it will be in principle the same reason (I ain't no filesystem expert).

Comment: It might just be a question of the network share reporting the consumed space  incorrectly. I’ve seen that on some older versions of Synology NAS (but that’s probably not what you’re using). What system does the share come from and what does it report about consumed space itself when looking at its local disks?

Comment: @StarCat I checked using command `du` (disk usage) and it gave me `1.4G` . Could the `Size on Disk` windows gives me be erroneous?

Comment: Well, Windows is just reporting what it receives from Samba. That value might be erroneous. I see you've found the solution yourself.

Comment: Yep I realized it afterwards so no issue with windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the smb `allocation roundup size` was (and I guess by default is) set to `1048576` (i.e. `1MB`), so even small files appear to have that size.

This was reported [here](https://redmine.ixsystems.com/issues/38525) as well. Lowering the value to `131072` as suggested there resolves the issue.