# 1-byte file takes up 2 MB (yes, megabytes) on 6 TB exFAT Veracrypt volume. Why?

Tags: hard-drive, formatting, exfat, veracrypt, advanced-format

Screenshot:

File properties of file that takes up 2MB of disk space for 1 byte of data:

[image]

The drive is a 6TB single partition, mounted via Veracrypt and formatted as exFAT. The sector size on my 2TB volume, formatted and mounted the same way, is 512KB-- also large, but not quite as ridiculous (shouldn't it be 512 *bytes*?).

Why in the world is the sector size a whopping 2MB here? Since it's an advanced format drive, shouldn't it be 4KB?

The drives were formatted using Veracrypt; <s>there was no option to specify sector size that I recall</s> there is a cluster size option, but it maxes out at 64KB for exFAT. The 6TB drives and all their data are about to be moved to a RAIDZ2 ZFS array, so I don't necessarily need to fix this directly, but I really want to know how/why this happened.

Comment: Are you sure you’re not confusing IO block size and “cluster size”, a filesystem property? exFAT supports *very* larger clusters. You can check using `diskpart`’s `filesystems` command after selecting the volume.

Comment: It's quite possible I am. However, the mounted Veracrypt volumes do not appear in `diskpart`, just the "`RAW`" disks/volumes.

Comment: What is content of the .text file

Comment: The single letter 'a'.

Comment: I don't know about the implementation details, but crypto-hashing a zero-length string is going to have an output that is the same length as an input that is at the input-string-size limit. In addition, the size on disk is probably an information leak, and I suspect that what is happening is that the reported size includes bytes shared by other encrypted files/blocks/padding. Kind of like an archive file, only lower level.

Comment: @Yorik No, Windows and Explorer don't know anything about the encryption, it's completely transparent. // I'll try what Windows does when formatting a 6 TB exFAT volume, and also what VeraCrypt does. It's quite possible the sector size dropdown is wrong for exFAT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I can confirm that exFAT on a 6 TB volume defaults to 2 MiB clusters on Windows 10. If I explicitly select 64 KiB, it uses that though. 64 KiB is also the maximum size Disk Management has in its dropdown list.

Incidentally, Microsoft has [an article on default cluster sizes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/140365/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs--fat--and-exfat) for various filesystems and Windows version. Unfortunately, it does not include the exFAT/Windows 10 combination, for whatever reason.

Experimentally, I determined the following defaults:

```
Volume size   Cluster size
  500 GiB          128 KiB
 1000 GiB          256 KiB
 1500 GiB          512 KiB
 2000 GiB          512 KiB
 3000 GiB            1 MiB
 4000 GiB            1 MiB
 5000 GiB            2 MiB
 8000 GiB            2 MiB
10000 GiB            4 MiB
20000 GiB            8 MiB
```

Those are just samples, I didn’t bother checking the actual ranges. The pattern is quite clear though. It switches at powers of two, ie. 512 GiB, 1 TiB, 2 TiB, 4, TiB, 8 TiB, 16 TiB, ...

It’s basically

```
(volume size “step”) / (221)
```

Or, more colloquially: Divide by two, go two SI suffixes lower. 16 TiB → 8 TiB → 8 MiB.

Comment: Maximum. Just as mentioned in the question.

Comment: It's the largest value in the dropdown list. That doesn't make it a technical limitation. Using `diskpart`, you can select all possible values.

Comment: Alright, I now understand what you meant.

Comment: That's surprising! But thank you for the answer and looking into it. I'll be careful not to just go with the default next time.

Comment: just found this out myself as well. 2MiB cluster size...I was getting gigabytes of wasted space for just 30MB of small files. Absolutely insane, wonder why Microsoft thought this was a good idea